# How to create PNG images with Visual Studio C++ 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, png

**IN**: Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, Windows 7

**OUT**: Some small ish PNG images that I will use as custom markers in Google Maps.

**Language**: C++ (or, if I really have to, C#)

*Extra: I need to be able to plot the alpha channel (the transparency). I used PNGwriter library on a Linux machine and that didn't offer this feature.*

*Extra 2: The .exe will run on a server each time a new custom marker is needed. (Markers have different colors and shapes)*

Edit: 1. I want to create a new image. 2. I need a library which I can't seem to find via Google yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want to convert from one file format to PNG using C++? Or that you want to render to an image and save the resulting image out as a PNG?

Either way, maybe you should take a look at FreeImage http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/features.html which is an open source image parsing/writing library that supports many formats, including PNG.

Comment: I want to create a image from zero. I.e. draw each pixel.I need a library, couldn't find one via Google.

Comment: Well, you stil need to save them out. There are lots of ways to write pixels to an image; Either code some blitting/rasterization code yourself (great learning exercise! Leads to greater things!) or use another library. Cairo <http://www.cairographics.org/> is a good vector graphics library which will allow you to draw to a surface using high level primitives. There are many others. You may just want to draw existing sprites into an image, rather than anything more complex. Don't overcomplicate things if you don't need to.

Answer (score 2):

I created a kluge to do this.  I used a common routine for getting the color (GetColor(red,green,blue,transparency)).  I printed in two passes.  The first pass would print to a 256 gray scale image.  GetColor() would return the transparency as a shade of gray.  The second pass would print to a 24-bit color image.  GetColor would return the RGB color.  After the two passes I merged the two bitmaps with the grayscale becoming the alpha channel for the PNG file.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not have any facilities built in for editing images. You'd need to find a library.

Comment: Yes, it's a library I am asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use .NET.

I would suggest the built in System.Drawing namespace, which is available in both flavors - C++ and C#. Assuming you aren't against using Visual C++ Express, you can always take it from there.

Here's a link to the "official" documentation: [System.Drawing Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx)
Within which is the System.Drawing.Graphics namespace, which is possibly what you would want to use.

AND here's a link to a nice little tutorial that will teach you how to import an image and draw on it (or possibly even draw it onto a bitmap): [The Wonders of System.Drawing.Graphics](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/67275-the-wonders-of-systemdrawinggraphics/)

Answer (score 0):

[Boost.GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/gil/doc/html/g_i_l_0174.html) can work with PNG.

Comment: I need something with basic plotting options (including alpha). If you can provide a plotting library for a different alpha-compatible image type that can then be converted via Boost.GIL to PNG I will consider choosing this for the answer.